# Error cambiar base de datos symfony2.7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, symfony2

Estoy creando un proyecto de `Symfony 2.7` y me gustaría cambiar el  documento `parameters.yml` a otra dirección host.

Mi problema es el siguiente: he trabajado en un host local con `Xampp` y, ahora, necesito enlazarlo en un hosting online. Claro primero he cambiado el nombre de la base de datos en `parameters.yml` como se indica en la foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero `symfony` no busca este valor, coge la configuración anterior. Al utilizar el comando `doctrine:database:create` siempre utiliza el nombre de la base de datos que existia antes en `parameter.yml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina el caché de Doctrine

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

y vuelve a ejecutar el proceso, por lo demás, tu error muestra que la BD ya existe, revisa en tu editor de base de datos si la borraste

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente se soluciona limpiando las cachés. El comando a ejecutar para ello sería:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```